# journald *reading* API?

Tags: api, systemd-journald

journald writes binary log files; and their format is explicitly subject to change.

The [Journald Reference Guide](https://www.loggly.com/resource/journald-handbook/) tells us, quote:

> While it can be useful to get used to journalctl to read logs, it’s by
> no means mandatory.

So, how can we read these files? Is there a journald reading API I missed? I couldn't find any yet.

Comment: I did. With variations. Up came APIs for *writing*. That's why I finally decided to ask here.

Answer (score 2):

Systemd (and journald) are written in C. They come with `sd-journal.h` header file and with C-API https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_journal_next.html# - `sd_journal_open` allows you to open logs and then read from them.

Other languages - https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/python-systemd/journal.html#example-polling-for-journal-events https://github.com/nyantec/rust-journald - most probably build on top of the C api.

Moreover, journald is open source - https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/968680b23d1629d33deeea98b4f2b5fd106075b5/src/libsystemd/sd-journal/sd-journal.c#L1916 - and the file format is documented - https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/journal-files/ . You can re-implement your own API on top of system-specific I/O operations to read journal files.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful links. The last item, though, I don't think is correct. Accessing the files directly / file format interpretation is discouraged; see https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/journal-files/ which I reached via the links above.

Comment: `I don't think is correct` What is not correct in it? `is discouraged` that does not mean it is false.

Comment: One *can* implement access code on top of direct file-I/O. But the strong recommendation not to do so is from the same (authoritative?) source you linked to. The API access you explained first should be safe, the file access not.

Answer (score 0):

Update: https://github.com/meta-bit/jjournal does the job for me, Java API for the purpose.

HTH